# C Confusion about pointer to pointers memory allocation?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

I apologize if this might be viewed as a duplicate, but I cannot seem to find a conclusive answer that satisfies my question.
So I have a struct with a self referential pointer to pointers.

```
struct Node {
    int id;
    int edge_count;
    struct Node **edges;
}

static struct Node s_graph[MAX_ID+1];
```

I  then have a function that allocates some memory.

```
int add_edge(int tail, int head)
{
    struct Node *ptail, *phead;
    ptail = &s_graph[tail];
    phead = &s_graph[head];

    ptail->edges = realloc(ptail->edges, ++ptail->edge_count * sizeof(struct Node *));
    if (ptail->edges) {
       *(ptail->edges + ptail->edge_count - 1) = phead;
       return 0;   
   }
   return -1;
}
```

The above seems to work just fine. However, I keep seeing posts about pointer to pointers that lead me to wonder if I need to do something like the following in add_edge:

```
struct Node *phead = malloc(sizeof(struct Node *));
```

However, this does not seem logical. There should be enough memory for ptail->edges to store this pointer after the realloc call. I am fairly confident that I did the allocation correctly (albeit, inefficiently), but it is kind of sending me on a mind trip ... So when people declare pointer to pointers (e.g., **ptr) and then allocate memory for both ptr and *ptr, wouldn't that technically make ptr a pointer to pointers to pointers (and maybe clearer to declare as ***ptr)? Or maybe I am wrong and missing something conceptually?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What you have looks ok to me. Except reallocing on every new node is a bit inefficient. Common practice is to alloc/grow in chunks. "So when people declare pointer to pointers (e.g., **ptr) and then allocate memory for both ptr and *ptr,". You have done the same. Except your second level (`*ptr`) is not dynamic memory but static memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the situation, there is no general answer. If you have a pointer to pointer, eg `Node**`, and you want to store new data into it, then you need to have two levels of allocations, otherwise one is enough.

```
struct Node** nodes = calloc(AMOUNT, sizeof(struct Node*));
```

Now you have an array of `struct Node*` elements, so each element is a pointer to a `struct Node`.

Now how do you fill this array? You could want to insert new nodes inside it. Then you wouold require to allocate them, eg

```
nodes[0] = calloc(1, sizeof(struct Node)); // <- mind Node, not Node*
```

But in your situation you just want to set the address to an element of an array of the static variable `s_graph`, so you don't need to allocate a second level, you directly set the value.

So:

```
struct Node** nodes = calloc(AMOUNT, sizeof(struct Node*));

nodes -> |   0   |   1   |   2   |   3   |

nodes[0] = calloc(1, sizeof(struct Node))

nodes -> |   0   |   1   |   2   |   3   |
             |
             |
             v
         |    NODE    |
```

But if you have `s_graph` you already have them allocated, so it's something like:

```
static struct Node s_graph[MAX_ID+1];
struct Node** nodes = calloc(AMOUNT, sizeof(struct Node*));

nodes -> |   0   |   1   |   2   |   3   |
s_graph -> |      N1      |      N2      |      N3      | 

nodes[0] = &s_graph[0];

nodes -> |   0   |   1   |   2   |   3   |
             |
             |----|
                  v
s_graph -> |      N1      |      N2      |      N3      |
```